# Multiple subscribers and single publisher in one python script?

Tags: ros, python, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having issues with getting this to work.  What I need to do is pull magnetometer data from the imu topic, pull gps data from gps topic, do calculations, and publish to cmd_vel topic.  It seems like it would be simple, but I can't seem to get it to work.  I can get both subscribers and the publisher to work simoultenously, but I cannot get the data to play together, and I'm pretty sure i'm getting stuck in a callback function.

My code is currently printing my bearing and heading, but it isn't moving, and I'm not sure what else I can try.

My most recent code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from geometry_msgs.msg import Vector3Stamped
from geometry_msgs.msg import Vector3

from math import radians
from sensor_msgs.msg import NavSatFix
import time
import numpy

global lat1
global long1


def call_head(um6):

    global heading
    global bearing 

    r = rospy.Rate(5);
    # rospy.loginfo("Bearing: %s", um6.vector)          #Print mag reading for bearing
    z = um6.vector.z
    y = um6.vector.y

    angles = Vector3()

    heading = numpy.rad2deg(numpy.arctan2(z, y)) + 90

    angles.x = heading
    angles.z = bearing

    call_bear_pub = rospy.Publisher("navStuff", Vector3, queue_size=10)


    call_bear_pub.publish(angles)


    r.sleep()
    return "done heading"


def call_nav(navsat):

    global heading
    global bearing 

    global lat1
    global long1


    r = rospy.Rate(5);
    # rospy.loginfo("Latitude: %s", navsat.latitude)        #Print GPS co-or to terminal
    # rospy.loginfo("Longitude: %s", navsat.longitude)

    angles = Vector3()

    lat1 = navsat.latitude
    long1 = navsat.longitude

    ###########################################################
    lat2 = 30.210406
    #                                   Destination
    long2 = -92.022914
    ############################################################

    dLon = long2 - long1
    y = numpy.sin(dLon) * numpy.cos(lat2)
    x = numpy.cos(lat1)*numpy.sin(lat2) - numpy.sin(lat1)*numpy.cos(lat2)*numpy.cos(dLon)
    
    bearing = (numpy.rad2deg(numpy.arctan2(y, x)) + 360) % 360

    angles.z = bearing

    call_nav_pub = rospy.Publisher("navStuff", Vector3, queue_size=10)
    
    # if (heading != 0):
    #   call_nav_pub.publish(angles)
    # else:
    #   pass



    r.sleep()
    return "done bearing"

def call_move(data):


    r = rospy.Rate(5);

    pub = rospy.Publisher('/husky_velocity_controller/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)


    move_cmd = Twist()
    turn_cmd = Twist()

    ###########################################################
    lat2 = 30.210406
    #                                   Destination
    long2 = -92.022914
    ############################################################



    move_cmd.linear.x = 2
    turn_cmd.angular.z = radians(45)


    heading = data.z
    bearing = data.x

    
    
    turn_angle = heading - bearing

    rospy.loginfo("bearing: %s", bearing)
    rospy.loginfo("heading: %s", heading)
    

    if (turn_angle > 180):
        turn_angle -= 360
    elif (turn_angle < -180):
        turn_angle += 360
    else:
        turn_angle = turn_angle

    if (abs(lat1-lat2)<.0005 and abs(long1-long2)<.0005):
        pub.publish(Twist())
        r.sleep()
    else:
        if (abs(turn_angle) < 8):
            pub.publish(move_cmd)
            rospy.spin()
        else:
            pub.publish(turn_cmd)
            r.sleep()
    return "done move"      

    

def run():
    rospy.init_node('navigate_that_husky')
    rospy.Subscriber("/imu_um6/mag", Vector3Stamped, call_head)
    rospy.Subscriber("/gps/fix", NavSatFix, call_nav)
    rospy.Subscriber("navStuff", Vector3, call_move)
    
    rospy.spin()
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

---

That's actually what I tried first, bit I couldn't get it to work.  I switched to this method because of [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/174485/return-a-value-from-a-callback-function/)

I'm sure I just don't understand how to use global variables enough.  I'll post a simple version my attempt at using global variables.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist, Vector3Stamped
from math import radians
from sensor_msgs.msg import NavSatFix
import geometry_msgs.msg
import time
import numpy

lat = 0
lon = 0

def callback(navsat):


    global lat 
    global lon 

    lat = navsat.latitude
    lon = navsat.longitude

    return lon
    return lat

def printer():

    global lat
    global lon

    rospy.loginfo("Latitude: %s", lat)
    rospy.loginfo("Longitude: %s", lon)
    return

def listener():
    rospy.init_node('navigate_that_husky')
    rospy.Subscriber("/gps/fix", NavSatFix, callback)
    rospy.spin()
    
def run():
    listener()
    printer()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

That doesn't work for me either.  Am I missing something?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232216/multiple-subscribers-and-single-publisher-in-one-python-script?/) by [tercelkisor](https://answers.ros.org/users/26132/tercelkisor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-04-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As suggested why don't you use a class and some flags

`#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from geometry_msgs.msg import Vector3Stamped
from geometry_msgs.msg import Vector3

from math import radians
from sensor_msgs.msg import NavSatFix
import time
import numpy

global lat1
global long1

Class Foo: 

    def call_head(um6):
        z = um6.vector.z
        y = um6.vector.y

        self.angles = Vector3()

        self.heading = numpy.rad2deg(numpy.arctan2(z, y)) + 90

        self.angles.x = self.heading
        self.angles.z = self.bearing

        self.send_bear_ = True
        return "done heading"


    def call_nav(navsat):


        self.angles = Vector3()

        self.lat1 = navsat.latitude
        self.long1 = navsat.longitude

        dLon = self.long2 - self.long1
        y = numpy.sin(dLon) * numpy.cos(self.lat2)
        x = numpy.cos(lat1)*numpy.sin(self.lat2) - numpy.sin(self.lat1)*numpy.cos(self.lat2)*numpy.cos(dLon)

        self.bearing = (numpy.rad2deg(numpy.arctan2(y, x)) + 360) % 360

        self.angles.z = self.bearing

        self.send_nav_ = True
        
        return "done bearing"

    def call_move(data):

        move_cmd = Twist()
        turn_cmd = Twist()

        

        move_cmd.linear.x = 2
        turn_cmd.angular.z = radians(45)

        self.heading = data.z
        self.bearing = data.x


        turn_angle = self.heading - self.bearing

        rospy.loginfo("bearing: %s", self.bearing)
        rospy.loginfo("heading: %s", self.heading)


        if (turn_angle > 180):
            turn_angle -= 360
        elif (turn_angle`

Basically once you are receive the message the flag gets set and you can send it on the publisher.
If you want them all together simply make sure that all must be true at the same time.

This should take care of timing issues. It did for me.

Sorry for the poor formatting I'm in a hurry.

---

Originally posted by [Sood](https://answers.ros.org/users/26384/sood/) with karma: 20 on 2016-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2016-04-21**:
+1 for using a class. You could even get rid of the ugly global variables `lat1` and `long1`. Another improvement in my eyes would be to remove the complete `navStuff` topic. Just call `call_move()` directly.

**Comment by [tercelkisor](https://answers.ros.org/users/26132/tercelkisor/) on 2016-04-24**:
I think I've decided to go this route.  I've never used classes before, so I'll do a little reading on that first.  Thanks.

**Comment by [Sood](https://answers.ros.org/users/26384/sood/) on 2016-05-22**:
Great! Did I answer your question successfully? Does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Oh dear this code is a mess.

Have you read and UNDERSTOOD all tutorials under http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials?

There are a few things wrong here.

1. You don't need all these `rospy.Rate`.
2. Don't create the publishers in your callbacks. Define them global and just `publish` in your callbacks.
3. Do other nodes need the data you publish on the `navStuff` topic? If not remove this whole topic from you program. There are much cheaper and easier ways to handle data inside your program e.g. store it in a global or member variable.

If I understand you right you need data from both `/imu_um6/mag` and `/gps/fix`. As soon as you got both you need to process it and publish to `/husky_velocity_controller/cmd_vel`. What you have to do is, store the data from these two topics in a global variable. In your `run` method you wait until you got your data and then process it and publish it.

---

**Update**

That already looks way better.
I would recommend you to read some good Python tutorials. The learning curve of ROS itself is quite steep. But learning ROS and Python together can lead to heavy headache.

```
global lat 
global lon 

lat = navsat.latitude
lon = navsat.longitude
```

This is correct. You store the latitute and longitude in the global variables.

```
return lon
return lat
```

This is useless. 1. Callbacks don't process return values. 2. The second return is never reached since the function ends with the first return. (The correct way to do such stuff in Python would be `return (lon, lat)`)

```
rospy.spin()
```

This call is blocking forever, so `printer()` is never invoked. Remove this `rospy.spin()`

Your `printer()`method could look like

```
def printer():
    while not (lat != 0 and lon != 0):
        rospy.sleep(.01)
    rospy.loginfo("Latitude: %s", lat)
    rospy.loginfo("Longitude: %s", lon)
```

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2016-04-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tercelkisor](https://answers.ros.org/users/26132/tercelkisor/) on 2016-04-19**:
I've edited my question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-20**:
Note: I'd be surprised if `lat` or `lon` ever really will be `== 0`, seeing as they are floats.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2016-04-20**:
Yes I also thought about this. In this while I check if they got a value from the callback. At the time of declaration `lat = 0 lon = 0` they are integers. As soon as the callback stores values in them they become floats and the while ends.

**Comment by [tercelkisor](https://answers.ros.org/users/26132/tercelkisor/) on 2016-04-20**:
So I removed the rospy.spin(), and the script just closes itself after printing "lat = 0 long = 0"  I've read that the spin function is required to keep the script from "jumping out or something.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2016-04-21**:
Did you insert the while loop?

**Comment by [tercelkisor](https://answers.ros.org/users/26132/tercelkisor/) on 2016-04-24**:
Yes, I tried the while loop.  It sort of works, but it won't stop the script when I crtl+c.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2016-04-25**:
while not (lat != 0 and lon != 0) and not rospy.is_shutdown():

should do the trick